# How to check duplicates in an array with a time complexity of O(n) in C lang?

Tags: time, space

Well if I use this for example:-

```
for(i=0 ;i<n ;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)

     {
        if(array[i] != array[j])
         return 0;
     }

}
```

in this case the time complexity is O(n^2) but how can I check duplicates in an easier and shorter way in order to make the time complexity O(n)? also what does 
a space complexity of O(k) while k is constant and k is smaller then the inputs size? (k is smaller than n).Thx for any suggestions

Comment: Order your array and check consecutive elements

Comment: you mean I need to sort it by size for example? if it is then how does this affects the complexity of time?

Comment: If the range of your data is known and reasonable then use a counting sort for O(n), otherwise use a more general sort for O(n log n).

Comment: Is there any way to use nested loops with complexity time O(n)?